# Why can't a RAID controller mimic a drive controllers actions on a URE?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, disk-controller

There is a fact: **a URE renders an entire member of a RAID array as bad, but a URE DOES NOT render an entire drive as bad outside of an array.**  What is the technical difference that causes this?  They both are seen in a similar fashion at the OS level so it must be something below the OS and formatting.

From my understanding, when a single member of a RAID 5 fails, the RAID controller starts to rebuild a replaced disk by comparing the other values along with parity to write the correct value on the new disk.  When a URE happens, "it" senses "corrupt data" via the "read error", "it" cannot correct the "read error", and it stops rebuilding and marks the second member as bad.  If you have single redundancy, this renders the array unusable.

**Why is the ENTIRE array unusable when encountering a URE?  Why not just that stripe of information?**  It seems the location in the array could easily be noted, the file table checked, and the files corrupted listed so the corrupted files could be re-added to the array from backups.

For example, **in a single disk, the drive controller would just mark the sector as bad and move on; the drive controller would NOT mark the entire drive and partition(s) therein as "bad".  Why can't a RAID controller mimic that and have the same or similar result?**

Also, secondary question for backround that might relate is a URE a "hard error" where every read from the same sector fails (platter related) or a "soft read" error that happened one time (data transfer related) but the data on the platter is still good? If the latter, it would beg the question of why not just try the read again?  Or is it the former?

**Why can't a RAID controller mimic a drive controllers actions on a URE?**

Tl;Dr

**[This](https://superuser.com/questions/700177/why-ure-fails-raid-rebuild-and-renders-raid-5-unusable)** question is the same question effectively but the rant seemed to throw the answer and tone of the entire thread sideways. The "answers" of *"The goal of RAID is to keep the file system usable after a disk dies. Not to replace a backup of guarantee a successful rebuild."* and *"an Unrecoverable Read Error while reading the source you're building from, then it's impossible to properly rebuild the array from that corrupted source."* do not answer this question.

No rant here.  There must be some fundamental technical difference between the way the RAID controller "sees" things compared to a single drive that must cause this behavior; what is that technical difference?  *I can logically answer my own question; a raid controller sees the array as a single unit where a drive thinks of things in terms of individual sectors.  But it seems a work around to this could be implemented similar to how a single disk does things and would allow things to be usable again so I must be missing something.*

*[This thread over at Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/545782-raid-5-unsafe-where-is-the-proof) alludes to there is a real issue with UREs but it is convoluted.  Lots of links in the thread to follow though.*

Comment: A proper RAID controller will by no means kick a drive simply because it encounters an unrecoverable read error. Is your question based on experience or supposition?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator "Supposition".  There are many articles and reports on a URE will render a RAID 5 array unusable for "some" reason;   Hence the well publicized move away from RAID 5 due to UREs.  However I am always open to I might be mistaken!

Comment: Fair enough. The most common reason that a RAID controller will kick a drive for encountering "one" uncorrectable error is if the drive doesn't have a RAID-friendly firmware. In this case the drive attempts to correct the error, taking up to perhaps 30 seconds to do so, during which time the RAID controller (which expects such errors to be reported but not fixed by the drive) will "give up" on the drive and kick it from the array believing the entire unit to be failed.

Comment: It would be helpful to link one or two of the more reliable sources upon which your question is based.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Added link to question.

Comment: I've read part of that linked post, and it seems to be specifically challenging someone's claim that *RAID 5 arrays will almost always fail a **rebuild***. How do you see this contributing to your question?

Comment: Further in the thread there is mention of both UREs are not "called out" as such; for example sometime it is simply a hung system for unknown reason, or a failed rebuild but the drive seems fine, among other things.  Point is URE's do happen, but we just really don't know when and can't seems to get good evidence of what, why, and what gives.